# Different single page templates for taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

In my WordPress theme I created the custom post type `articles`. I also created two taxonomies called `article` & `news`. 
How can I display each taxonomy in its own single template? 
For now it only displays using the `single-articles.php` template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the single_template filter in your functions file with the correct [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'single_tax_term_template' );
function single_tax_term_template( $single_template ) {

    global $post;

   if ( has_term( '', 'article' )  ) {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/article.php';
     }

    if ( has_term( '', 'news' )  ) {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/news.php';
     }

    return $single_template;
}
```

This code targets all terms in news and article taxonomies.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to read the [taxonomy template article](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) on WordPress.org for that information.

Comment: This article doesn't contain an answer to the question related to the single post template.

Comment: It is the first bullet point on the page.